# passing structure from c++ to python

Tags: python, c++, ctypes

C++ code

```
typedef struct Box
{
   public:
      int length;   // Length of a box
      int breadth;  // Breadth of a box
      int height;   // Height of a box
};

extern "C"
{
    //struct Box __declspec(dllexport) GetAllInfo();
    TESTAPI struct Box * GetAllInfo();
}

extern "C"
{
    TESTAPI struct Box * GetAllInfo()
    {
       Box *Box1 = new Box;
       Box1->height = 5;
       Box1->length = 6;
       Box1->breadth = 7;

       cout << "Info is : " << Box1->height<<Box1->length<<Box1->breadth <<endl;

       return Box1;
   }
}
```

Python code

```
import ctypes
from ctypes import Structure, c_int, c_double, windll
from ctypes import *
from ctypes import wintypes
from collections import namedtuple

#astdll = windll.CDll
class Box(object):

    def __init__(self,height,length,breadth):

        self.height = height
        self.length = length
        self.breadth = breadth

#class Box(Structure):

# _fields_ = [

# ("height", ctypes.c_int),
# ("length", ctypes.c_int),
# ("breadth", ctypes.c_int)

# ]

Box = namedtuple("Box", "height length breadth")

lib = cdll.LoadLibrary("F:\\QT SCADA\\forPythonDLL\\Neha_Test\\Debug\\Neha_Test.dll")

#lib.GetAllInfo.restype = POINTER(Box)

s = Box

global result

result = lib.GetAllInfo()

#s = result
s.height = 20

print (result.height)
print (s.height)
```

This is the error:

> Running script: "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\test.py"
>
> Info is : 567
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\test.py", line 41, in
>
> print (result.height)
>
> AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'height'

Comment: this is pretty illegible. please see [this help](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362/473285) which explains how to format your code

Answer (score 2):

Thanks fr all the help....:)

I got this code

its working fine

```
import ctypes
from ctypes import Structure, c_int, c_double, windll
from ctypes import *
from ctypes import wintypes
from collections import namedtuple


lib = cdll.LoadLibrary(DLL_PATH)

class Box(Structure):
_fields_ = [
    ("length", c_int),
    ("breadth", c_int),
    ("height", c_int)]

 lib.GetAllInfo.restype = POINTER(Box)
result = lib.GetAllInfo()
print ("result type: ", type(result))
print ("-"*30)
print ("result: ",result)
print ("-"*30)
print (result.contents)

Box1=result[0]
print(Box1.height)
```

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% sure on this, but at a guess I'd say your issues lies in the fact that the C++ code for GetAllInfo returns a Box pointer (type `Box*`), which is effectively just an integer referring to a location in memory. You're then trying to get the height attribute of this integer pointer, which is resulting in the error `AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'height'`.

Try returning a Box object (as below), not a Box pointer, and see if that fixes it.

```
TESTAPI struct Box * GetAllInfo()
{
   Box *Box1 = new Box;
   Box1->height = 5;
   Box1->length = 6;
   Box1->breadth = 7;

   cout << "Info is : " << Box1->height<<Box1->length<<Box1->breadth <<endl;

   return Box1;
}
```

becomes

```
TESTAPI struct Box GetAllInfo()
{
   Box *Box1 = new Box;
   Box1->height = 5;
   Box1->length = 6;
   Box1->breadth = 7;

   cout << "Info is : " << Box1->height<<Box1->length<<Box1->breadth <<endl;

   return (*Box1);
}
```

Comment: That  is not a good idea since it creates a memory leak, Box1 is not deallocated since there is no corresponding delete.

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing C and C++. Your updated code works because `ctypes.Structure` fixes this issue for you. You need to also release the memory you allocate. How you do this depends on what your program needs to do with a `Box`. One possibility is to use an in/out parameter in `GetAllInfo` (implementation left as an exercise for the reader).

---

```
struct Box {
    int length;   // Length of a box
    int breadth;  // Breadth of a box
    int height;   // Height of a box
};

extern "C" TESTAPI Box* GetAllInfo() {
    Box *Box1 = new Box;
    Box1->height = 5;
    Box1->length = 6;
    Box1->breadth = 7;

    cout << "Info is : " << Box1->height << Box1->length << Box1->breadth << endl;
    return Box1;
}
```